# Meaning of present tense

Tags: verbs, tenses

Two questions here.

1) A (high quality and honest) citizen journalist wrote a report on JAN 30,

"Yesterday Police announced they were investigating the death as a suicide. The wife of the victim is a member of Lost Voices."

Does this imply that (one or more of these are true?)

- The wife currently is a member (as of JAN 30) -- option A
- The wife was a member yesterday (as of JAN 29) -- option B

2) Another reporter wrote,

"Yesterday Police announced they were investigating the death as a suicide. The wife of the victim was a member of Lost Voices."

Does this imply that (one or more of these are true?)

- The wife was a member yesterday (as of JAN 29) -- option A
- The wife currently is a member (as of JAN 30) -- option B
- The wife currently is not a member (as of JAN 30) -- option C

Context: the news reporting site uses two related guides:

http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/WN:NA (never assume)

http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/WN:SG#Verb_tense (what verb tense to use in articles)

Context #2:

We are having a dispute about this, and one of the reports shares these links

https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/verb_tenses/verb_tense_consistency.html

https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/verb_tenses/active_verb_tenses.html

And mentions 'habitual actions' which may be relevant to the question.

Please share your independent advice about this. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: If the wife is still alive and still an active member of that group, then the simple present is called for (“The wife of the victim *is* “). It is almost certainly true that she *was* alive and a member yesterday (the 29th), too, but it would be weird to report it that way because *it’s still true*, and what’s true *now* is more important than what was true *yesterday*. If the wife had died along with the husband, then you’d say (“X’s wife, who was also killed in the incident, *was* .... ). It’s easier if you imagine we’re talking about heights instead: “Jane is 5’3” ‘ (she was on th 29th too)

Comment: @DanBron The report is due to be published today. Yesterday she was alive and was a member. We don't know whether this is the case today.

Comment: I was using “today” as shorthand for the 30th (the day the paper was published and you read it) and “yesterday” for the 29th, the day of the guy’s death. Sorry if that was confusing. The newspaper (on the 30th) was *asserting* at that time (the 30th) the wife was alive and a member. That doesn’t mean they knew it for a fact: if someone dies and the reporter only knows that fact, it’s reasonable for the reporter just *assume* the wife is alive as she was on the 29th (meaning, with all her fixed qualities, like being a member, or being 5’3”).

Comment: @DanBron: Yeah, but “Jane is blonde” and “Jane is bald” don’t really tell you anything about how she looked yesterday. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  A lot depends on context.  “The wife is a member of *X* ” *probably* means that she has been for a while, and still is.  “The wife is selling their house and buying a new, smaller one” probably refers to decisions made after the husband’s death.  (To make matters worse, this refers to *intent* to do things in the future, and not necessarily action she is taking on the 30th.) //  Case #2: Option C (the wife currently is not a member) is almost certainly true, but Options A and B might both be false.  If she “was a member”, she might have quit years ago.